# How to store persistent data in phone's cache for angularjs

Tags: angularjs, memcached, ionic-framework, cachefactory

I want to store some data in the phone's cache, like localStorage, but localStorage isn't safe.

I got some data stored to the cacheFactory from the serviceAPI. I can use this data until the application is closed, but when I restart the application the saved data is undefined.

I would like to find a way to store info in the phone's cache not session cache. How can I achieve this?

Comment: why dont you just store the data in sqlite?

Comment: This is the team project, my partner don't know SQL well. So, i want chose  another way.